# Python create dictionary from file

Tags: python

I have this Python code that is not reading what I want it to read exactly. 
For the worst cars, Ford should be the one with the max number of worst cars but I keep getting the result of Chevy ssr any help?

This is the format of the file I'm working with:

```
1899 Horsey Horseless
1909 Ford Model T
1911 Overland OctoAuto
1913 Scripps-Booth Bi-Autogo
1920 Briggs and Stratton Flyer
1933 Fuller Dymaxion
1934 Chrysler/Desoto Airflow
1949 Crosley Hotshot
1956 Renault Dauphine
1957 King Midget Model III
```

And this is my code:

```
import string

def car_dictionary(file_obj):
    car_dict = {}
    for line in file_obj:
        line =line.strip()
        line =line.split()
        manufacturer = line[1]
    if len(line) ==3:
        car_tuple = (line[0],''.join(line[2:]))
    else:
        car_tuple = (line[0])
    if manufacturer in car_dict:
        car_dict[manufacturer].append(car_tuple)
    else:
        car_dict[manufacturer] = [car_tuple]

return car_dict

def max_worst_cars(car_dict):
    worst_manufacturer =("")
    worst_count = 0
    for a,b in car_dict.items():
        if len(b) > worst_count:
            worst_manufacturer = a
            worst_count = len(b)
            print("Worse Manufacturer is: ", worst_manufacturer)
            print("Cars: ")
    for y, m in car_dict[worst_manufacturer]:
        print(y,m)

file_obj=open("cars.txt", "r")
car_dict = car_dictionary(file_obj)
file_obj.close()
max_worst_cars(car_dict)
```

Comment: Paste a small sample of the file in your question, instead of putting links to a share site which will probably we invalid very soon, and then your question will too.

Comment: Best way to this kind of storing and reading data from/to file is to use existing methods. Save your data as JSON or YAML and read it from file.

Comment: Note that the link for the data doesn't lead people who are not signed up with FileDropper to the file.  That's not good.

Comment: Does the indentation for `car_dictionary()` __exactly__ match the way it appears in your program? As it is, it's only processing the last line of the file.

Comment: yeah that's how its matched and that's exactly what its doing only reading the last line of the file

Comment: Your code would error with correct indentation as your have cases where you only have a year and manufacturer

Comment: `car_tuple = (line[0])` won’t create a tuple, add a `,` at the end: `car_tuple = (line[0], )`

Comment: with correct indentation your `car_dict[worst_manufacturer] ` returns `['1909', ('1958', 'Edsel'), ('1971', 'Pinto'), ('1995', 'Explorer'), ('2000', 'Excursion')]`, you won't be able to unpack as you have a single element in there

Comment: This code doesn't properly handle manufacturers with a name longer than one word, such as `Briggs and Stratton`.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the incorrect indendation of your code (which was probably a mistake when you pasted it into the question), there is only one real problem with it:

```
car_tuple = (line[0])
```

This won’t make a tuple, but will just assign `line[0]` to `car_tuple`. To make it a tuple, you need to include a comma:

```
car_tuple = (line[0], )
```

However, this won’t change the problem you will have later when you try to unpack the tuples, so you should just use an empty string as the second tuple item:

```
car_tuple = (line[0], '')
```

Then, your code results in the correct result:

```
Worse Manufacturer is:  Ford
Cars:
1909
1958 Edsel
1971 Pinto
1995 Explorer
2000 Excursion
```

---

That being said, you can do this all a bit simpler by using a few more Python tricks. Here is my 8-line solution, plus comments so you understand what’s going on:

```
# We’re going to use `defaultdict` to handle the whole “when there is
# already an element in the dictionay, append to the list, otherwise
# create a new entry with a single list item” thing. `defaultdict` just
# allows us to append without having to manually initialize new keys.
from collections import defaultdict

# Files should always be opened with the `with` statement, to ensure
# that they are closed correctly afterwards. Since we’re reading, we
# don’t need to specify the open mode ('r' is the default).
with open('cars.txt') as f:
    # We initialize our dictionary as a defaultdict, where each item
    # is automatically initialized with an empty list.
    cars = defaultdict(list)

    for line in f:
        # We put strip and split in a single line. Since we always
        # get at least two values from your file format, we can just
        # unpack the values directly. We collect additional unpacked
        # values (so index 2 or above) in a list called `rest` (the
        # star symbol does that). That list may be empty, or not.
        year, manufacturer, *rest = line.strip().split()

        # We just append (because it’s a defaultdict, we don’t need
        # to initialize it) to the list of the manufacturer a tuple
        # with the unpacked year, and the joined values of the rest.
        cars[manufacturer].append((year, ' '.join(rest)))

# Now that we collected our cars dictionary, we want to find the
# manufacturer that has the highest number of cars. Since `cars` maps
# the key manufacturer to the a list of cars (car tuples actually), we
# essentially want to get the dictionary item with the maximum length
# in the item value. We use the built-in `max` function with a custom
# key function for this.
# `cars.items()` returns a sequence of key/value tuples of the
# dictionary. We want to get the maximum value of those key/value
# tuples, and as a metric for “maximum value” we use a function that
# takes this tuple `(manufacturer, listOfCarTuples)` and returns the
# length of that `listOfCarTuples`. So in the key function, `x` is that
# tuple, so `x[1]` is the list of car tuples. So the length of that list
# is the metric of the current dictionary item which we want to get the
# maximum from.
worst = max(cars.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))

# `worst` is now `(manufacturer, listOfCarTuples)` where
# `len(listOfCarTuples)` has the maximum value.
print(worst)
```